# Имена полей и атрибутов Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Пример: У меня приходит массив POST с атрибутами "firstName, lastName".

```
`"firstName" => "qwerty",
 "lastName" => "ytrewq",`
```

В БД этой модели поля называются "userName, userSurName".

```
 public function rules()
    {
    return [
        [['userName', 'userSurName'], 'string'] 
    ];
}
```

Каким образом можно присвоить полям из БД значения атрибутов с поста?

Comment: Добрый день. Дополните вопрос кодом модели, где определяются "firstName" и "lastName".

Answer (score 1):

```
$model->userName = Yii::$app->request->post('firstName','');
```